# Тестовый режим хостинга

Tags: хостинг

Я заказал хостинг, в тестовом режиме, но когда на мой сайт заходит больше 8 человек он уже начинает глючить, если я проплачу хостинг, таже фигня будет Оо использовал провайдера [guru-host.ru](http://guru-host.ru) а тариф выбрал Guru-Host 1000

Comment: В чем проявляются "глюки"?

Comment: Пишет Service Temporarily Unavailable

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю что в тестовом режиме вам что-то там урезают, это не в их интересах.
Если сайт падает, или долго думать начинает, то посмотрите в сторону кода сайта, запросы в БД, настройки ПО на севере.

Ибо тариф то такой себе, понтовый. А вы можете захотеть там второй youtube развернуть.

Comment: Мне выбивает Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: Это из-за хостинга, у них одна тачка обслуживает сотни сайтов мелких, кто-то затролил эту тачку своим сайтом, все повалились.

Из FAQ одного из хостеров:
Каждому аккаунту на сервере выделено определенное количество процессов-рабочих, обрабытывающих запросы пользователей. Запросы поступают на сервер и становятся в очередь. Легкие запросы обрабатываются быстро, а тяжёлые проблемные — медленно, тормозя продвижение очереди. Когда длина очереди достигает определенной величины, сервер перестает принимать новые запросы, возвращая ошибку 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable).

Answer (score 0):

[Отчего возникает ошибка 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)](http://www.jino.ru/support/faq/problems/error-503.html#error-503)